# "Morphisms" for fractal dimension

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, fractals

Let $A\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ a set with [Hausdorff–Besicovitch fractal dimension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hausdorff_dimension) $d \le n$, then be a continuous function $f:A\to \mathbb{R}^m$ with $m\ge n$.

1. Under what conditions the HB fractal dimension is preserved? It seems that if $f$ is [Lipschitz continuous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lipschitz_continuity) with inverse $f^{-1}$also being Lipschitz continuos, then both $A\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ and $f(A)\subset \mathbb{R}^m$ have the same HB fractal dimension (equivalently $f$ is a bi-Lipshchtiz continuous or Lipeomorphism).
2. Suppose that $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}^n$ is a homeomorphism such that for each subset $A\subset\mathbb{R}^n$, $\dim(A)=\dim(f(A))$. Does it follow that $f$ is a Lipeomorphism? [edited in response to a comment]

Comment: Such maps are usually called "bilipschitz" (or ["lipeomorphisms"](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1445936/what-is-preserved-by-lipeomorphisms)) and it is an easy exercise to see that they preserve Hausdorff dimension. Your question 2 is very unclear, I truly do not understand what are you asking in this item. As for 3, then **no**, it would not make sense.

Comment: @MoisheKohan with question 2, I meant: "can we weaken the requirement to be a lipeomorphism and still having the same HD fractal dimension?"

Comment: I think, a meaningful form of (2) can be: Suppose that $f: R^n\to R^n$ is a homeomorphism such that for each subset $A\subset R^n$, $dim(A)=dim(f(A))$. Does it follow that $f$ is a Lipeomorphism? I do not know an answer even if $n=1$.

Comment: $f : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ defined by $f(x) = x^3$ and its inverse both preserve H-B dimension, but neither $f$ nor its inverse $x^{1/3}$ are Lipschitz.

Answer (score 5):

$f : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ defined by $f(x) = x^3$ and its inverse both preserve H-B dimension, but neither $f$ nor its inverse $x^{1/3}$ are Lipschitz.

A known condition on a map $f$ so that $\dim f(A) \le \dim A$ for all subsets $A \subseteq \mathbb R^n$ is:  There exist sets $T_n$ so that $\mathbb R^n = \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty T_n$ and $f$ is Lipschitz on $T_n$ for all $n$.  Both $f$ and $f^{-1}$ have this property in the example above.

This can also be weakened.  For example, things like
$$
|f(x)-f(y)| \le C|x-y|(-\log|x-y|)\quad\text{when }|x-y|<\delta
$$
replacing Lipschitz.